# Using Maverick, I modified my hosts file to deny access to facebook, doesn't work as intended

Tags: macos, mac, firefox, dns, hosts

I modified both `/etc/hosts` and `/private/etc/hosts` here it is

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
0.0.0.0 www.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 facebook.com
0.0.0.0 login.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 www.login.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 fbcdn.net
0.0.0.0 www.fbcdn.net
0.0.0.0 fbcdn.com
0.0.0.0 www.fbcdn.com
0.0.0.0 static.ak.fbcdn.net
0.0.0.0 static.ak.connect.facebook.com
0.0.0.0 connect.facebook.net
0.0.0.0 www.connect.facebook.net
0.0.0.0 apps.facebook.com
```

Apparently firefox still can connect to facebook, but apparently a `ping facebook.com` times out as expected. I even restarted firefox without success.

I've also ran

```
dscacheutil -flushcache;sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Did you clear your DNS cache?  Make sure that Firefox simply isn't loading a cache of the content.  Actually navigate around Facebook.

Comment: I did a hard refresh yes. about the dns refresh, it's in the question.